# Manually compiled linux kernel, kernel log not showing during boot

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, grub

I'm asking the exact opposite of what normally people as, I want to see the kernel boot log instead of hiding it, unfortunately it's not showing, I don't if it's a kernel issue or a grub issue.

I just compiled linux-5.15.0 using the default x86_64_defconfig. I updated grub to ad the entry, here is my kernel command-line,

```
root=/dev/sda2 rw loglevel=5
```

Needless to say nothing is being shown, the kernel successfully loads and starts systemd but there is no log of it showing. I induced a kernel panic by not specifying a root partition, even then no output, the system locks up in a black screen, no error message saying "kernel panic, not syncing, unable to mount....yada yada"

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

PS : I booted the kernel in qemu using the same arguments, here it shows the kernel log properly. Also I have the filesystem drivers within the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kernel might not have the driver for your display.

If you have a sufficiently modern UEFI system, then you must have `CONFIG_SYSFB_SIMPLEFB=y` and `CONFIG_FB_SIMPLE=y`.

Comment: Hi, I just realized this and recompiled it, now it's working.